# AJAX request lagging

Tags: php, ajax

i have an AJAX request that fires a few SQL queries and adds the data to session

```
console.log(new Date());    //log 1
$.post( 
    "get_all_snos.php",
    { owner: owner, bucket_id:bucket_id, is_npl:is_npl },
    function(data) {
        console.log(new Date());    //log2
        alert(data);    //timestamps present in the alert
    }
);
```

The first console log gives me the initial time (**Ex: 13:34:44**)
The second console log gives me the ending time (**Ex: 13:34:59**)
There is a gap of approximately 15 seconds.
BUT...
My php code is something like this..

```
<?php
    echo date(' H:i:s')." | ";
    // some queries fired
    echo date(' H:i:s')." | ";
    // some queries fired
    echo date(' H:i:s');
?>
```

The timestamps i get from the **alert** as something like this

> **13:34:58** | **13:34:58** | **13:34:59**

Now the mystery is that what happened between **13:34:44** to **13:34:58**
How does sending an AJAX request take almost 14-15 seconds to just send the data??
i cant seem to figure out what's happening.

I have tried using javascript's AJAX too, but it didnt help.

Comment: That's literally all of the code that's relevant to this AJAX call?

Comment: By the way, check the network inspector of you debug console in the browser to see if sending the call is delayed for any reason.

Comment: yeah, i just fire queries using ajax and update the DB.

Comment: I'm not sure this could be relevant, but instead of `echo`ing, try to append the `date`'s to a string and echo that in the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If that is a good representation of all the code, you should not have that much of a delay. This leads me to think that you have Network issues (use Firebug's Net panel for instance).

Hope it helps.